# Recursive boolean lambda C++

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, lambda, boolean

For some reason this lambda statement doesn't want to compile:

```
bool DepthFirstSearch = [](Graph *g, bool *ch, stack<int> &S, int v, int w) -> bool
{
 //Here is recursive DFS code
};
```

with the error: `no suitable conversion function from: "lambda[]bool()->bool" to bool exists`.

My question is why?

Comment: do you want to store the lambda itself or the result? For the result add a `(...);` (with the arguments for the call) at the end (after the `}`) to actually call it. If you want to store it, to call it later, use `auto DepthFirstSearch = [](..)...;`

Comment: Well, you're trying to initialize a `bool` value with a lambda expression. Did you mean to invoke the lambda at the end of that expression (`[](...) -> bool {...}(<arguments go here>)`)?

Comment: A recursive lambda? That's difficult, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the lambda isn't `bool`. You could use `auto` to make this work

```
auto DepthFirstSearch = [](Graph *g, bool *ch, stack<int> &S, int v, int w) -> bool { ... }
```

or use `std::function` to specify the return type explicitly, but that would be quite cumbersome. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function.

Generally it is easier to just use auto, otherwise you'd have to change the type of the variable every time you change the parameters of the lambda.

Comment: I think compilers should refuse lambdas whose initializers reference themselves

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it recursive, then you have to capture the lambda (by ref). To do that, you need to give it a named type:

```
std::function<bool(Graph*, bool*, stack<int>&, int, int)> DepthFirstSearch = 
    [&](Graph *g, bool *ch, stack<int> &S, int v, int w) {
        // bunch of code here that possibly calls DepthFirstSearch
    };
```

You can't just do `auto DepthFirstSearch = [=](...){...}` here because the lambda will need to know the type of `DepthFirstSearch` in order to capture it - and if you just use `auto` then the type won't exist until after the lambda-expression is processed, which is too late. Hence the `std::function<...>`.